# Map a YAML file to interfaces in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, yaml

I am new to JavaScript. I need to map a YAML file to Interface in Javascript. I have a YAML file which is like the below:

```
- provider_name: SEA-AD
  consortiumn_name: SEA-AD
  defaults: thumbnail
  Donors:
  - id: "https://portal.brain-map.org/explore/seattle-alzheimers-disease#Human-MTG-10x_SEA-AD_Male_TissueBlock"
    label: Registered 2/20/2023, Rebecca Hodge, SEA-AD
    description: "4 x 4 x 5 millimeter, 0.11 millimeter"
    link: "https://portal.brain-map.org/explore/seattle-alzheimers-disease"
    sex: Male
    Blocks: 
    - id: https://portal.brain-map.org/explore/seattle-alzheimers-disease#Human-MTG-10x_SEA-AD_Male_TissueBlock
      label: Registered 2/20/2023, Rebecca Hodge, SEA-AD
```

And an interface in typescript which is:

```
export interface Provider {
    provider_name: string;
    provider_uuid: string;
    consortium_name: string;
    defaults: string;
    donors: Donor[]
}

export interface Donor {
    id: string;
    label: string;
    description: string;
    link: string;
    age: number;
    sex: string;
    bmi: number;
    blocks: Block[];
}

export interface Block {
    id: string;
    label: string;
}
```

Now I want to map the interface with the TypeScript file in JavaScript.
So far, I am unable to map the inner variables (Like the Donors in YAML file). I have done following:

```
cosnt data = load("YAML File");  
const provider = {
    provider_name : data.provider_name,
    consortium_name : data.consortium_name,
    dafaults: data.defaults,
    donors: data.Donors.map(function (donor ) {
```

I am new to JavaScript. Am I doing it right? Is there any other way to do this?? The map function is not available in JavaScript. Any leads or references will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: can you share the implementation of the `load` function?

Comment: sure. I imported load from js-yaml.   import { dump, load } from 'js-yaml';

Comment: tbh i don't think you need to explicitly extract the data from the loaded file. since the data in the file is in the format in which you want it to be, why not just straightaway use the `data` variable?

Comment: ah I thought you use sth different than `js-yaml`.

Comment: So, I want to load the data which is in YAML file, and convert it to JSON format. Also there is another YAML file from where I need to get data and append it to the JSON file

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to read-in your yaml file as a js object.
You could use packages like `js-yaml`: `npm install js-yaml -g`.
You merge objects like this:

```
var file1 = 'input1.yml',
    file2 = 'input2.yml',
    yaml = require('js-yaml'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    obj1 = yaml.load(fs.readFileSync(file1, {encoding: 'utf-8'}));
    obj2 = yaml.load(fs.readFileSync(file2, {encoding: 'utf-8'}));
    obj = { ...obj1, ...obj2 };
```

The objects already are json objects.

This is not TypeScript. But it is just to show the strategy.

Answer (score 0):

You could validate the loaded YAML is in the correct JSON format using something like AJV, and have it cast the data to your type:

```
import Ajv, { JSONSchemaType } from "ajv"
const ajv = new Ajv()

interface Provider {
  provider_name: string;
}

const schema: JSONSchemaType<Provider> = {
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    provider_name: {type: "string"}
  },
  required: ["provider_name"]
}

const validate = ajv.compile(schema)

// NOTE: I assume this parses the YAML into a JSON Object
// using something like js-yaml
const data = load('file.yaml')

if (validate(data)) {
  // data is Provider here
  console.log(data.foo)
} else {
  console.log(validate.errors)
}
```

You could also just cast it. Something like this:

```
const data = load("YAML File") as Provider;
```